# How can I sort and filter a drupal VIEW using the date field provided in Content Profile

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

For a site I'm making for a sports club I want to create a block through views that shows the upcoming birthdays off all members registered on the site. I am aware that you can do this for nodes, but somehow I can't access the Profile: Birthday field through views. Not if I make a views using nodes, neither if I make a view using users.

I have Views, CCK, Content Profile and Date installed. I work with drupal 6 on a php 5.1.6(I can't get the administrators to update the server). But I can't get it all to work together... Any leads for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since date profile field is serialized in database (drupal 6), it is not possible to sort.

http://drupal.org/node/475150

However, instead using a profile field, you can add a date cck field to your profile content type wich will be sortable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the "content profile" relationship in views ? If I remember well, this relationship will let you access to the content profile fields you're looking for.

Comment: I just tried this, but it doesn't show up in the list when adding relationships sadly